# People who are overselling

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for people that tries to oversell something. They often uses words like excellent, fantastic, exciting, Great (used it 7 times). For context, this particular list of words is from a recruiter in a single email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an informal term "sex up"

From [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sex-up)

> to change something in order to make it seem more interesting, exciting, or important
>
> They brought in an advertising agency to try to sex up the city’s image.

[Overstate](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/overstate)

> to talk about something in a way that makes it seem more important, impressive, or serious than it really is.
>
> He may have overstated his ability in the interview.

You can also look at these [synonyms and related words - to exaggerate and overstate](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-exaggerate-and-overstate)

Answer (score 1):

**[hype](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hype)<sup>1</sup>** (ODO)

> **noun**
>   *mass noun*
>   *informal*
>   **1** Extravagant or intensive publicity or promotion.
>       *‘his first album hit the stores amid a storm of hype’*
>   
>         **1.1** *count noun* A deception carried out for the sake of publicity.
>         *‘is his comeback a hype?’*

*Use case:*

> The issue: enterprises need help clarifying the line between hype and reality. … more context, and a voice of reason amidst all the sales talk.
>   (Paul Ruelas, [Catching the SD-WAN wave: the cost savings hype and MPLS …](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3269022/sd-wan/catching-the-sd-wan-wave-the-cost-savings-hype-and-mpls-misconceptions-need-more-explanation.html), Network World, 18-Apr-2018)